# How to replace values of one multiband raster with the values of another multiband raster, where they overlap? [QGIS]

Tags: qgis, raster, multi-band, overlapping-rasters

I've seen this question asked many times with regards to single band rasters, where you can use raster calculator. What about when you have two 3-band images?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use mosaicking available in the SAGA Toolbox or Raster > Misc > Merge.